# What is the basename format for `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` files?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Given a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/foo.list` file of the form

```
deb http://my-domain.tld/my-apt-repo mydistro mycomponent othercomponent
```

what kind of names can I expect for the associated files created by `apt-get update`?

There seems to be some transformation from apt repository URL to the `basename`s of the associated `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` files. Is this documented and, if so, where?

Comment: [2.5. Debian package management internals](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_debian_package_management_internals)

Comment: @bac0n Thanks! In a subsection of the item you referenced, I found this: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_fetching_of_the_meta_data_for_the_package  It has a good example showing how the various fields comprise the basename, but it's not exactly a specification.